# Prototype mouseenter and mouseleave in IE7

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I am trying to create a Dropdown menu script in Javascript using Prototype+Script.acul.us

here is the sample website

http://195.184.94.170/

on mouseenetr on "Über uns" a dropdown menu will be displayed it work fine in all browsers except IE. By onmourover on any of the menu item the Dropdown menu start to flicker.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

My hunch is you have events bubbling but cannot test it myself since it works perfectly on my IE7. In your [mouse handlers](http://195.184.94.170/javascript/dropdown_new.js) try putting an [`event.stop();`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/stop/) when show/hide is used.

Another possibility is bubbling occurs because there is an `<a>` inside the `<li>` and entering the `<a>` creates two enter events and a leave event (as the mouse moves from the `<li>` to the `<a>`). This is more difficult to fix, you could place the event handlers directly on the `<a>` itself which avoids any bubbling, or you could use a timeout for hiding the menu and allow it to be cancelled by the later enter event.